# How to remove Default space between Two ListTile

Tags: flutter, list, dart, flutter-dependencies

Column(
children: [
ListTile(
visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: 3),
contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 0.0),
//contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),

```
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: (){},
              icon:const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined,size: 40,) ),
              title: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
    
                },
                child: const Text("PICK UP",style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 19,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color:Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 182, 55)
                ),)
                ),
              subtitle:const Text("Mysore,",style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.black
              ),),
          ),
          
          ListTile(
            visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: 3),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical:0),
            
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: (){},
              icon:const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined,size: 40,) ),
              title: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
    
                },
                child: const Text("DROP OFF",style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 19,
                  fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color:Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 182, 55)
                ),)
                ),
              subtitle:const Text("Bangalore,",style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.black
              ),),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

i added twlo list tile inside column but i dont ant space between two ListTile

Comment: There is no space in between the tiles. You want them to be less high? Try out leaving the `visualDensity` or give the `vertical` there a negative value

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your listtile with sizedbox or  use negative value in visual density

```
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 45,
          child: ListTile(
leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.location_on_outlined,
                  size: 40,
                )),
            title: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  "PICK UP",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 19,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 182, 55)),
                )),
            subtitle: const Text(
              "Mysore,",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
            height: 45,
              leading: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.location_on_outlined,
                    size: 40,
                  )),
              title: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: const Text(
                    "DROP OFF",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 19,
                        fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 182, 55)),
                  )),
              subtitle: const Text(
                "Bangalore,",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ))
      ],
    );

or use negative value in visual density

Column(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.location_on_outlined,
                size: 40,
              )),
          title: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: const Text(
                "PICK UP",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 19,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 182, 55)),
              )),
          subtitle: const Text(
            "Mysore,",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.location_on_outlined,
                size: 40,
              )),
          title: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: const Text(
                "DROP OFF",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 19,
                    fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 182, 55)),
              )),
          subtitle: const Text(
            "Bangalore,",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 5),
          ListTile(
            visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -2),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 0),
            leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined, size: 40,)),
            title: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  "DROP OFF",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 19,
                      // fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
                      // fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 182, 55)
                  ),
                )),
            subtitle: const Text(
              "Bangalore,",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.black),
            ),tileColor: Colors.yellow,
            dense: true,

          ),
          ListTile(
            visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -2),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 0),
            leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined, size: 40,)),
            title: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  "DROP OFF",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 19,
                      // fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
                      // fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 182, 55)
                  ),
                )),
            subtitle: const Text(
              "Bangalore,",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.black),
            ),tileColor: Colors.yellow,
            dense: true,

          ),

        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contentPadding` property to remove padding,
set this property to **zero**